# Como realizar testes unitários no nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, testes-de-unidade

Gostaria de fazer testes unitários no [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), estou utilizando o `grunt-jasmine`, porém ele não reconhece a variável `exports`, `module` e nem `required`.

Há uma maneira de resolver isso ou alguém sugere um framework de testes mais adequado ao node? Estou utilizando em conjunto com o [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

As minhas configurações:

```js
jasmine: { src: 'src/**/*.js', options: { specs: 'specs/**/*Spec.js' } }
```

Comment: Utilizo o grunt-jasmine, que utiliza o jasmine-node.

Comment: Apenas para ser chato: O correto é "teste de unidade", e não "teste unitário".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Assert

Um dos módulos do node é o [assert](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert). Não é uma ferramenta completa para testes unitários mas é possível utilizá-lo sem nenhum adicional para realizar seus testes.

### Métodos

- [`fail`](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_fail_actual_expected_message_operator): Compara dois valores (estilo *atual* e *esperado*).
- [`ok`](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_value_message_assert_ok_value_message): Confere se a expressão passada é verdadeira.
- [`throws`](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message), [`doesNotThrow`](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_doesnotthrow_block_message): A função passada deve/não deve lançar uma exceção.
- [`ifError`](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_iferror_value): Testa se o valor passado é verdadeiro; útil para testar variável de erros.

Além de vários métodos *equal*: [equal](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_equal_actual_expected_message), [notEqual](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_notequal_actual_expected_message), [deepEqual](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_deepequal_actual_expected_message), [notDeepEqual](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_notdeepequal_actual_expected_message), [strictEqual](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_strictequal_actual_expected_message), [notStrictEqual](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_notstrictequal_actual_expected_message).

---

## Nodeunit

Baseado no assert explicado acima, nodeunit é uma das opções mais simples de escrever seus testes unitários. Suporta testes assíncronos.

### Métodos

Os métodos para teste são os mesmos do assert descritos acima. Além deles, para cada função de teste o nodeunit lhe envia um objeto com as seguintes funções:

- `expect(quantidade)`: Número de asserções que será feita neste teste. Se um número de asserções diferentes do passado for feita o teste falha. A chamada desta função é opcional.
- `done`: Termina o teste atual. Esta função **deve** ser chamada.

### Escrevendo o módulo de teste

Para escrever um módulo de teste é muito simples, basta expor suas funções de teste e receber nelas um paramêtro com o objeto *test* do nodeunit, exemplo:

```
exports.testaAlgo = function (test) {
    test.expect(2);
    test.ok(true, "este teste irá passar");
    test.ok(false, "este teste irá falhar e essa mensagem será exibida");
    test.done();
};
```

### Executando os testes

Basta instalar o nodeunit via npm:

```
npm install -g nodeunit
```

E depois executar o teste:

```
nodeunit meuTeste.js
```

A saída é algo do tipo:

```
$ nodeunit meuTeste.js
✖ testaAlgo

Assertion Message: este teste irá falhar e essa mensagem será exibida
```

---

## Configurando os testes unitários no projeto

Uma das formas de configurar seus testes no seu projeto é utilizar o *package.json*, exemplo:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "nodeunit testes/*.js"
}
```

Desta maneira basta executar `npm test` para executar seus testes.

Para não ter que instalar o nodeunit de maneira global em sua máquina (paramêtro `-g` do `npm install`), pode-se utilizar o nodeunit local da pasta *node_modules*:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./node_modules/.bin/nodeunit testes/*.js"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Não estarei respondendo sua pergunta, mas existem outras alternativas de testes para o node.js.

Se você está procurando algo mais ao estilo TDD:

- o módulo `assert` embutido no node.js
- nodeunit (que faz uso do módulo `assert`) - https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit

Se você prefere ao estilo BDD, como o Jasmine:

- tem o Mocha (serve tanto pra TDD como para BDD) - http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/
- Vows (bem legal esse) - http://vowsjs.org
- should.js (também usa assertion para fazer BDD) - https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/

Eu conheci esses módulos e frameworks fazendo a revisão do livro Node.js in Action. Recomendo o livro.

Comment: OK. Irei utilizar o nodeunit através do plugin grunt-contrib-nodeunit, já que uso o grunt para o build do projeto. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Como tu resolveu a minha dúvida, e resolvi utilizar outro framework de testes (como tu sugeriu), alterei o título e vou dar OK na tua resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, Daniel. Embora não sejam oficialmente suportados também existem plugins Grunt para o Mocha e pro Vows. Se você atualizar seu perfil com email, podemos trocar umas ideias também. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo usar o http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha e http://chaijs.com para testes unitários usando o estilo TDD e BDD para testes completos e eficazes. Caso também precise testar APIS internas ou externas, use o github.com/visionmedia/supertest