# Qual é a finalidade da função "assert()" e quando devemos utilizá-la?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, testes, assert

Segundo o manual do PHP

> assert — Confere se uma afirmação é FALSE

Ou

> assert() verifica a assertion informada e toma a ação apropriada se
> seu resultado é FALSE.

E há este exemplo de uso da função `assert()` que é utilizada para checar se uma declaração é falsa:

```
<?php
assert(true == false);
echo 'Hi!';
```

[Fonte.](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.assert.php)

---

## Pergunta

Mesmo lendo a respeito da função `assert()` eu ainda não consegui compreender qual é a finalidade dela, e quando eu devo utiliza-la. Se ela serve apenas para checar se uma *afirmação/declaração* é falsa porque não usamos um `if (condição falsa/verdadeira)` logo de uma vez ao invés dela?

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade da função `assert()` e quando devemos utilizá-la?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Definição

É uma função de [*assertion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)). Existe em quase todas linguagens. Algumas possuem mecanismos mais sofisticados e alternativos.

> Asserção - Proposição que se julga verdadeira

[Dicionário Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/asser%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Então, é um recurso para provar se algo é verdade. Não é um mecanismo de decisão (pergunta) como é um `if`. É apenas uma afirmação.

## Quando usar

Usamos ele quando esperamos que sempre seja verdadeiro. Em um `if` esperamos que as duas coisas aconteçam. No `assert` um resultado falso indica problemas. É um mecanismo de documentação e não do algoritmo em si. O único objetivo dele é dizer se algo confere ou não com a expectativa que o programador escreveu ali.

Em PHP não vejo as pessoas usando. O tipo de aplicação (não precisa do máximo de robustez, afinal são *scripts*, certo?) e o tipo de programador típico de PHP não se preocupa muito com isso.

Não usamos o `if` porque esse código não faz parte da aplicação, faz parte do "teste" da aplicação. O objetivo é outro. Em produção ela "não existe". Em desenvolvimento ajuda identificar situações onde o código não está se comportando como se espera.

Essa função deve ser usada apenas para testes formais ou para testes eventuais em depuração. Por isso ela pode ser desligada. Então em produção ela não deve rodar, e não terá custo (em PHP tecnicamente tem porque precisará ser interpretada, mas não executada, mas esse custo é/deveria ser desprezível). Obviamente algumas ferramentas podem ser usadas para automatizar o processo de verificação.

## Mecanismo é diferente de resultado

É o que eu falei em uma [resposta sobre o `if`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165499/101). Os programadores precisam dissociar a ideia de uma expressão booleana e `if` andarem juntos. Nesse caso a expressão booleana serve para dizer **para o programador** se o código está ok, mas é o mecanismo usado que faz isso. A expressão booleana só gera um resultado, o que será feito com ele é assunto do programador. Pode ser usado em:

- um cálculo,
- em uma instrução de controle de fluxo que toma uma decisão,
- só imprimir,
- ou se apenas quer saber se aquilo está correto,
- etc.

## Validade e qualidade do uso

A qualidade da ajuda que ela dá para testar é tão boa quanto a capacidade do programador de identificar o que pode dar errado. Programadores ingênuos tem a tendência a achar que se encher de `assert()` ou outras coisas semelhantes o código ficará à prova de bala (como ocorre com exceção). Programadores relapsos não se preocupam com testes, de nenhum tipo. Programadores pragmáticos sabem quando usar cada coisa.

Isso se obtém estudando cada recurso, vendo o uso em bons códigos de terceiros e usando sua própria experiência. É normal ter dificuldade de usar no começo não só o `assert()`, quase qualquer coisa em programação. Por isso é sempre interessante ter mentores de qualidade para ir mostrando em cada caso se está fazendo certo ou não.

## Testes e contratos

Note que isso nada tem a ver com [testes de unidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101) e outros testes existentes fora do código. Mas `asserts` costumam ser usados dentro deles.

Ele pode ser visto como um [*design by contract*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) de pobre. Por isso é muito comum ser usado para avaliar parâmetros de funções, resultados que elas retornam, ou se o estado de um objeto saiu de uma situação válida em algum momento. Em algumas linguagens ele faz parte da linguagem e ajuda o compilador produzir códigos melhores. Em uma linguagem dinamicamente tipada é mais importante ainda e a verificação de tipos é um dos maiores usos.

Um exemplo seria verificar se o parâmetro recebido está dentro de uma faixa de valores que se espera. Lembrando que isso difere do `if` porque nesse caso se vier um número fora da faixa significa que houve um erro de programação, não era uma situação esperada. Se testes formais forem feitos adequadamente em toda aplicação, poderá achar problema no uso daquela função antes de mandar para produção.

## Abuso

Algumas pessoas usam como controle de código em produção. Isso pode ser considerado um abuso, apesar de funcionar. Em geral a execução é interrompida, como uma exceção, afinal se um `assert` é falso, há um erro de programação que precisa ser corrigido. É possível até lançar uma exceção opcionalmente.

Quando faz-se isso não pode desativar o seu uso, aí o `assert` passou ser usado no lugar do `if`, misturou mecanismos, usou o teste onde deveria ser a lógica do algoritmo.

## Complemento de leitura

- [Existe alguma funcionalidade similar ao Assert (afirmações) em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128991/101)
- [Python, diferença entre assert e raise?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127118/101)
- [Pra que serve o assert no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85323/101)
- [Como realizar testes unitários no nodejs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 pela resposta bem completa. Eu também não vejo programadores PHP usando `assert`, talvez em função do sistema de tipos da linguagem.

Comment: @eightShirt editei, na verdade a linguagem deveria usar mais ainda. PHP 7 tem mecanismo que, em parte, dispensa o `assert` para verificar tipos.

Comment: @Maniero no caso do assert ser falso o que acontece? O script aborta com uma mensagem? Ou vai alguma mensagem para o logo?

Comment: @JorgeB. na verdade eu não lembro mais, faz temp oque não uso PHP e nunca fui um grande usuário dessa função, e eu sei que andou mudando em versões recentes. Que eu me lembre você liga e desliga ou configura o que fazer, mas não me peça detalhes :D