# Para que serve usar Assert.assertNotNull() nos frameworks?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, assert

Tenho visto no framework do Spring Boot que eles usam bastante o `Assert.assertNotNull()` para validar as variáveis se estão recebendo valores nulos.

É correto usar esse mesmo tipo de abordagem no desenvolvimento de aplicações já que o objetivo de usar o JUnit é para teste unitário?

Comment: Não manjo de Java, mas chuto que é pra gerar uma exceção e parar o código caso receba `null`.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido. Java já possui o `Objects.requireNonNull()`. `Assert` é uma classe do JUnit para testes unitários, até onde sei, e é nesse contexto que faz sentido usar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, a princípio é bastante correto, asserções deveriam ser padrão em todo método que deseja-se robustez. Claro, pode não ser, depende do objetivo da pessoa. Não é correto usar qualquer coisa sem entender bem aquilo e for o que deseja de fato. Não pode usar as coisas no automático e achar que está correto porque funciona.

Para esse caso específico seria melhor ainda que a linguagem não aceitasse um valor nulo por padrão e assim a própria tipagem se encarregaria disso, então sempre que a tipagem resolve, um teste de unidade é desnecessário, assim como se a tipagem não resolver talvez uma asserção possa resolver.

Se isso for bem-feito, é possível apenas fazer um teste de cobertura para garantir que o código foi testado em todas as situações e depois que tiver tudo em ordem pode desligar a asserção sem incorrer em custo de processamento, ou se preferir e for necessário deixar a verificação durante a execução e lançar uma exceção quando algo errado for passado para o método.

Se quiser que a verificação esteja presente em todas as situações aí não está fazendo uma asserção e o mais correto é uma verificação padrão da linguagem.

Por não trabalhar no dia a dia de Java não sei se tem métodos de asserção melhores que esse usado, na verdade nem sei exatamente qual é esse método já que várias bibliotecas podem ter um com o mesmo nome, mas a asserção é uma técnica muito válida e útil, gostaria que as pessoas usassem mais.

Pode entender mais em [Qual é a finalidade da função "assert()" e quando devemos utilizá-la?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166719/101).

Imagino estar falando de teste de unidade que é o termo correto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Java desde a versão 1.4 tem _assertions_, no caso a palavra-chave `assert`, que é acionada quando o recurso é habilitado explicitamente ao rodar a JVM (por razões de compatibilidade retroativa) e a aplicação é compilada em modo debug, ou seja, não é acionada em produção. Imagino que por essas razões é um recurso pouco conhecido e utilizado.